# Convert multiline to polygon

Tags: postgis

[perfect result Shapefiles](http://geomatique.evimbec.ca/data/polygon.zip)

How I can convert this closed line to polygon with PostGIS?

I tried many functions like `ST_Polygonize`, `ST_MakePolygon`, `ST_BuildArea`. I got some results, but not a perfect one.

The ArcGIS function Feature to Polygon generated a perfect result.

The shapefile is available on request.

[image: closed line feature]

Comment: Shapefile or WKT would be much appreciated as well as how the perfect result looks like, or WKT of that too.

Comment: give a sample to look around.

Comment: The polygon result was made available, not the input polylines.